# Drag and drop on kendoDiagram

Tags: drag-and-drop, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

Hi I'm trying to develop a work flow editor as a drag, drop and draw, so that user can drag and drop shapes and connect them to create a diagram, for this I'm using Kendo UI draggable and drop target but the drop target has to be kendoDiagram widget. I'm facing issue in making the kendoDiagram as a dropTarget because it is already initialized as kendoDiagram please help me resolving this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
function setDropTargetOnDiagram(element) {
    $telerik.$(element).kendoDropTarget({
        drop: function (e) {
            var draggable = e.draggable,
                element = e.dropTarget,
                diagram = element.getKendoDiagram();

            if (draggable && draggable.hint) {
                var item = draggable.hint.data("data"),
                    offset = draggable.hintOffset,
                    point = new kendo.dataviz.diagram.Point(offset.left, offset.top),
                    transformed = diagram.documentToModel(point);

                item.x = transformed.x;
                item.y = transformed.y;

                diagram.addShape(item);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It would be nice, if you would add some explanation.